# Magento Top Nav: Add CSS class to first category using PHP

Tags: php, magento

I need help with customizing Navigation.php in Magento. I'm using Superfish to create a top nav bar that will always have the first tab open if no other tab has been selected (this Superfish nav bar example has the second tab as the default: http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#sample4 )

However, since Magento generates the top menu using PHP, I need to insert CSS class sfHover using PHP as well.

This is the code that Magento uses to insert CSS classes into the top nav links:

```
 $classes = array();
    $classes[] = 'level' . $level;
    $classes[] = 'nav-' . $this->_getItemPosition($level);
    if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)) {
        $classes[] = 'active';
    }
    $linkClass = '';
    if ($isOutermost && $outermostItemClass) {
        $classes[] = $outermostItemClass;
        $linkClass = ' class="'.$outermostItemClass.'"';
    }
    if ($isFirst) {
        $classes[] = 'first';
    }
    if ($isLast) {
        $classes[] = 'last';
    }
    if ($hasActiveChildren) {
        $classes[] = 'parent';
    }
```

This is the code Magento uses to determine each category's position in the top nav:

```
 protected function _getItemPosition($level)
{
    if ($level == 0) {
        $zeroLevelPosition = isset($this->_itemLevelPositions[$level]) ? $this->_itemLevelPositions[$level] + 1 : 1;
        $this->_itemLevelPositions = array();
        $this->_itemLevelPositions[$level] = $zeroLevelPosition;
    } elseif (isset($this->_itemLevelPositions[$level])) {
        $this->_itemLevelPositions[$level]++;
    } else {
        $this->_itemLevelPositions[$level] = 1;
    }

    $position = array();
    for($i = 0; $i <= $level; $i++) {
        if (isset($this->_itemLevelPositions[$i])) {
            $position[] = $this->_itemLevelPositions[$i];
        }
    }
    return implode('-', $position);
}
```

I've tried the following to add my CSS class:

```
if ($this->_getItemPosition($level) == "1") { 
        $classes[] = 'sfHover';
    }
```

and

```
if ($position == "1") { 
            $classes[] = 'sfHover';
        }
```

But neither of them work, either with the three equal signs === or with single quotes.

Does anyone with more Magento / PHP knowledge than me know what I can do? Thanks in advance!

Update: Superfish script strips out sfHover class. Need to add "active" class instead to Navigation.php.

I can do it in top.phtml with the following code on a manually coded nav:

```
    <?php $_anyActive = false; foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category) { $_anyActive = $_anyActive || $this->isCategoryActive($_category); } ?>
<li class="level0 nav-1 level-top first parent <?php echo !$_anyActive ? 'active' : '' ?>">
```

But I don't know how to integrate that with the code from Navigation.php...

Comment: 1. That navigation is heavily cached, so make sure you're clearing your cache after making your changes.  2. What happens when you var_dump($position);

Comment: 1. I've been clearing the cache every time I made a change to the file.

2. I'll try the var_dump. I've never done one before. Thanks!

Comment: Update: Tried doing a var_dump and all it returned was "null". I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly, but tried 2 different approaches and still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following. Change

```
if ($isFirst) {
    $classes[] = 'first';
}
```

to

```
if ($isFirst) {
    $classes[] = 'first sfHover';
}
```

That should insert both the class first and sfHover into the first element in the menu array. The other way you could do this is remove the auto-created menu from your theme and replace it with content blocks to deliver your menu items. It's not as elegant but gets the job done.

Comment: This did input "sfHover" into the first item of each nav ul, but for some reason, the Superfish script stripped the sfHover out (I can tell because the source HTML has sfHover in it, but Firebug is showing the element without the class applied). 

I will need to figure out how to apply an "active" class to the first nav item only when no other items are active. Please see edited question. Thank you for your input!